# Time taken for Hadoop job to execute

Tags: java, hadoop, timing

Is there an API to figure out how long a Hadoop job took to execute (exactly -> no hacks.)?

Comment: you want to know just after job finish, or later on, from the history?

Comment: just after the job has completed (--> when progress touches 100%)

Answer (score 7):

I think the simplest way is to measure time in Your driver class. Is it ok for you?
I mean something like this:

```
   long start = new Date().getTime();
   boolean status = job.waitForCompletion(true);            
   long end = new Date().getTime();
   System.out.println("Job took "+(end-start) + "milliseconds");
```

Comment: This is actually the way I am doing it now using a multi-threaded environment I was just wondering if Hadoop keeps some kind of counter for this... Thanks though :)

Comment: Keep in mind that this isn't too exact (seconds-wise), because waitForCompletion() polls every n-seconds for the completion of the job.