# Why might hadoop job's "cpu time spent" exceed "Total time spent by all map/reduce in occupied slots"?

Tags: hadoop

I'm running CDH4 MR1 and looking at performance metrics in preparation for migrating to a new hadoop environment.

> Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)    0   0   3,801,573,232
>
> Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms) 0   0   30,152,549
>
> CPU time spent (ms)    0   0   5,151,794,220

Shouldn't CPU time be smaller than map millis+reduce millis because the map/reduce millis includes time when the CPU is both running and idle?

Comment: Your answer is here [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726388/what-does-cpu-time-for-a-hadoop-job-signify)

Comment: Does the time spent by all maps in occupied slots only include a subset of record reader, map, combiner, and partitioner? I didn't think so. If CPU time includes all phases of map/reduce, and the "total time spent by all maps/reduces" also includes all phases, then I still don't know why cpu time spent can be higher. I thought it would be lower if there's times when the CPU is idle during the map/reduce phases.